# Responsive fullpage.js: increase viewport to display full content

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js to design a fullpage carousel like site. The problem i am facing is in implementing the responsive features when the contents of a section (`see #section-1`, sections start from `section-0`)extends outside of the viewport.

**What do i want?**

Originally, i wanted to go with `scrollOverflow: true` but that didn't seem to work. It inexplicably cut off (hid) my elements midway. I read in other posts that the author discourages it's use. Then i used `respondsiveWidth`, set it to `980` since i wanted the responsive mode to kick in if the window is resized or loaded at a width less than 980px. The scrollbar works fine with this, but the height of the section remains the same i.e one full viewport. What i want is that this section to extend and accommodate its the entire contents.

**What have i tried?**

- I have added the class `fp-auto-height` and `fp-auto-height-responsive` to the particular section (`#section-1`) but that doesnt do anything, (**i also have a footer that has the class, its size is smaller than the viewport**)

  - I tried the following code:

`afterResize: function(){
     if((window).width < 980) {
        console.log("980");
        $("#section-1").addClass("fp-auto-height-responsive");
      }
    }`

i tried with CSS:

`#section-1,
    #section-1 .fp-slide,
    #section-1 .fp-tableCell{
        height: auto !important;
        min-height: 100%;
    }`

I also declared a separate class in CSS, added the above properties and did a `addClass` if `window.width is < 980` in my javascript file.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/BLxmwE?editors=0110)

Nothing i do seems to work and i a at the brink of a nervous breakdown.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i want is that this section to extend and accommodate its the
>   entire contents.

That's what `fp-auto-height-responsive` is for.

You might not be using it properly. You **do not** have to add it dynamically, but just add it the section you don't want fullPage.js to restrict the dimensions.

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height-responsive" id="section-1">
```

[Your demo](http://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/BLxmwE?editors=1010) is working properly for me. The blue section won't get the viewport size when responsive is fired and the text won't get cut.

If you are asking for your 2nd section, that's totally normal. You are using a `fixed` element. Same as if you use `absolute`. There's nothing fullPage.js can do for you in those cases. fullPage.js only STOPs restricting the dimensions of the section, which means it will take whatever dimensions it would take otherwise. And in your case, any fixed or absolute positioned element won't force its parent height to change.

Comment: I actually do have `fp-auto-height-responsive` on `#section-1. Doing so does increase the height of the particular section, but it seems to be overlapped by the subsequent sections See: http://imgur.com/a/SlIUz and http://imgur.com/a/0IewG. Is there a way to push them down?

Comment: @snow I already answered you why that's happening. Read my whole answer. I have nothing else to add.

Comment: It doesn't work even after i removed all elements with fixed positioning.

Comment: @snow you'll have to prove that with a reproduction.

Comment: in the same demo (now updated), on line # 71 i have commented out the fixed positioning for the #header. The #loader does still have fixed positioning but that's outside of #fullpage (i did try commenting it out too).

Comment: aha.. therein lay the problem. Thanks for your help and, of course, for the plugin.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as OP. Adding `fp-auto-height` works just fine for my footer section (that is less than viewport height) on a desktop but it cuts footer section content on mobile and does not let me scroll down the content of that section. On the other hand `fp-auto-height-responsive` works perfect on mobile (able to scroll down footer section content) but on desktop it makes the footer section 100% viewport height. I tried many combinations but none of them work. Dynamically changing class names doesn't work also.

Comment: @an0o0nym better create a new question here and provide a link to codepen or jsfiddle where we can inspect your code and try it out. And if you believe it's a fullPage.js bug, you can create an issue [on Github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues)